# can't change python version from visual studio code interpreter

Tags: python

I am trying to change python version from 3.9.0 to 3.7.6 from visual studio code interpreter. But when I checking python version from terminal it's showing me 3.9.0. see the picture[image]

how to switch from 3.9.0 to 3.7.6 in visual studio. see the second picture. it showing notification 3.7.6 at the bottom  but when checking version from terminal it's giving me 3.9.0

[image]

Answer (score 1):

probably you are still interested in answer to this question.
If you want to set the proper python interpreter, you can type it directly in terminal:

- specific python interpreter: `py -3.9`
- default python interpreter: `python`

Moreover, it is highly recommended to use default directory for python while installation.

[terminal commands for Win](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0WeE.png)